# Добавление строки в Excel python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Добрый день, перепробовал кучу методов, написал в итоге такой вот код

```
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy
import xlrd
BookName = 'Questions.xlsx'
wbOld = xlrd.open_workbook(BookName)
index = wbOld.sheet_by_index(0).nrows
wbNew = copy(wbOld)
sheet = wbNew.get_sheet(0)
# index1 = wbNew.sheet_by_index(0).nrows
sheet.write(index,0,'text')
sheet.write(index,1,'text1')
wbNew.save(BookName)
```

Проблема состоит в том, что после действий программы невозможно посмотреть сам `Excel` файл, не открывается в самом `excel'e` (в `numbers` открывается), как правильно записать файл, либо существует ли альтернативное решение задачи? 

*P.s дозапись производится в конец файла*

Comment: И почему-то не существует метода получения индекса у скопированного листа

Comment: [Связанный вопрос (если использовать Pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447758/writing-pandas-data-frame-to-existing-workbook)

Comment: попробуйте этот вариант дозаписи строк в excel-файл
https://riptutorial.com/ru/python/example/10145/put-list-data-into-a-excel-s-file-

Comment: Используйте библиотеку openpyxl

Answer (score 0):

Способ с пересозданием файла. Считывать xls можно следующей функцией:

```
import xlrd
def extract_sheet(tab_path_, sheet_name_):
    my_book = xlrd.open_workbook(tab_path_)
    my_sheet = my_book.sheet_by_name(sheet_name_)
    return my_sheet
```

Затем превратить таблицу в списки:

```
def xl_to_list(sheet_):
    my_table = []
    for m in range(len(sheet_.col(0))):
        my_row = []
        for n in range(len(sheet_.row(m))):
            my_row.append(sheet_.row(m)[n].value)
        my_table.append(my_row)
    return my_table
```

После можно работать с данными, проводить вычисления и пр., а после сохранить в новую excel:

```
import xlwt
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet(sheet_name_)
sheet1.row(index).write(line)
book.save(export_path)
```